# What is 'mis-registration' and 'mis-collimation' of television signals?

Tags: signal, signal-processing, signal-integrity, telecommunications, tv

I was reading about early televisions and television cameras, and I came across these terms with no explanation....

They appear on Google on a few pages, but again I cannot find a definition....

Comment: How early? Misalignment usually called "convergence" was a HUGE problem in colour TV systems. And collimation was a problem in the much earlier flying spot systems.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that it relates to the optics of TV cameras and flying-spot devices.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure, but I'd guess it means there were problems with the "sync" pulses that control the raster scan of the cathode ray tube: there's a pulse to start a new line, and a different pulse to start drawing a new frame from the top.

From there, the user just has to adjust the speed of the scan to make the picture cover the whole screen.

Here's a good reference: https://newbedev.com/programming-pattern-to-generate-vga-signal-with-micro-controller

(If a start-of-line pulse isn't properly created or detected, such that the lines are misaligned, I guess "mis-collimation" would be a reasonable name for the result. And then from context, maybe "mis-registration" describes a failure of the start-of-frame pulse?)